# Ускорение иерархического запроса Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть две таблицы, в одной содержится иерархия об адресных объектах (119772625 строк), в другой наименование этих объектов (1942868 строк), я хочу сформировать адреса в виде строк при помощи иерархического запроса, использую следующий код:

```
Select adh.objectid
       , replace(regexp_replace(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ad.typename || ' ' || ad.name, '^'), '\^', ', ', 2), '^') fulladres
From 
(
Select objectid
       , name
       , typename
From fias2.addrobj 
Where isactual = 1 
      and isactive = 1
) ad
     , 
(
Select objectid
       , parentobjid
From fias2.admhierarchy 
Where isactive = 1 
      and regioncode is not null
) adh
Where adh.objectid = ad.objectid

start with adh.parentobjid = 0
connect by nocycle prior adh.objectid = adh.parentobjid
```

Результат работы запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое таблицы иерархии и информации об адресных элементов соответственно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос выполняется в районе 17 секунд, индексация столбцов objectid и parentobjid только усугубляют ситуацию,  есть ли возможность как-то оптимизировать или ускорить это запрос или может быть как-то можно по-другому его написать?

DDL таблиц:

```
create table ADDROBJ (
ID number not null
, OBJECTID number not null
, OBJECTGUID varchar2(36) not null
, CHANGEID number not null
, NAME varchar2(500) not null
, TYPENAME varchar2(100) not null
, THE_LEVEL varchar2(20) not null
, OPERTYPEID number not null
, PREVID number null
, NEXTID number null
, UPDATEDATE date not null
, STARTDATE date not null
, ENDDATE date not null
, ISACTUAL number not null
, ISACTIVE number not null
)
```

```
create table fias2.ADMHIERARCHY (
ID number not null
, OBJECTID number not null
, PARENTOBJID number null
, CHANGEID number not null
, REGIONCODE varchar2(4) null
, AREACODE varchar2(4) null
, CITYCODE varchar2(4) null
, PLACECODE varchar2(4) null
, PLANCODE varchar2(4) null
, STREETCODE varchar2(4) null
, PREVID number null
, NEXTID number null
, UPDATEDATE date not null
, STARTDATE date not null
, ENDDATE date not null
, ISACTIVE number not null
)
```

План выполнения запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.S. Прошу прощения за качество скринов.

Comment: 1) Избавиться от подзапросов. 2) Использовать явный JOIN, а не запятые. 3) DDL таблиц и план - в студию.

Comment: @Akina, переделал запрос через JOIN и избавился от подзапросов, плодов это не принесло...
Добавил план выполнения (уже переделанного запроса с JOIN и без подзапросов) и DDL в вопросе.